# run commands on linux without interruption

Tags: linux, scripting, command

I have multiple commands . And I want to run all these commands on linux in one step without interruption ( wait until the output of the first command is finished then run the second and so on) .If there is any way to do this??.. I have all the commands to be run in text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
command1 ; command2 ; command3
```

If you wanted to pipe the output from command1 to command2 and finally run command3:

```
command1 | command2 ; command3
```

The semi-colon approach will not take into account whether the previous command was successful. If you want to stop execution on failure of command1 you can use:

```
command1 && command2 ; command3
```

Comment: I tried command1; command2 it's working but it only show the output and the first commamd and doesnot print the command of the other commands.. I need each command with its output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a single command line, you can connect the commands with semicolons:

```
command1 ; command2 ; command3
```

If you want the later commands to run only if the earlier ones succeeded, connect them with "&&":

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

Comment: I tried command1; command2 it's working but it only show the output and the first commamd and doesnot print the command of the other commands.. I need each command with its output

Comment: What do you mean by output? When I type 'pwd ; ls' I get the output of both commands.

Comment: For example: if I run: command1;command .. the output is:output1 output2.. and I want it to be: command1 output1 command2 output2

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers, you can use `;` and `&&` to terminate or separate commands in a list of commands, where `;` indicates simple unconditional sequencing and `&&` says to execute the following command only if the previous one succeeds.  (Other command separators include `&`, `|`, `||`, et al; see subsection *Lists* in section *SHELL GRAMMAR* near the beginning of the bash man page for details of how they work.)

To cause the commands from a list to display interspersed with outputs from those commands, you can use `set -x` to turn on the shell's XTRACE option.  Later, use `set +x` to turn it off.  The format in which XTRACE displays commands is controlled by the content of the PS4 parameter.  Here is an example transcript of two lines of command input and 14 lines of output:

```
$ alias d='date +%N'
$ d;d; set -x; d;d; echo PS4 is $PS4; d; set +x; d;d;d
726496303
729638881
+ date +%N
733073117
+ date +%N
736249778
+ echo PS4 is +
PS4 is +
+ date +%N
739730109
+ set +x
743027175
746206908
749367086
```